# Writing CFG for Languages

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Write a CFG for the given language L:

L = { a^i * b^j * c^k | i=j or i=k. Consider i >= 0, j >= 1, k >=0 }

I came up with:

S → XY | W

X → aXb | ε

Y → cY | ε

W → aW c | Z

Z → bZ | ε

Comment: This almost works, but not quite: it doesn’t ensure that there is at least one $b$.

Comment: Could you help me with the right CFG?

Comment: It requires only a couple of very minor modifications to what you already have. You just have to ensure that $X$ generates at least one $ab$ pair before disappearing, and that $Z$ generates at least one $b$ before disappearing. You could, for instance, replace the $Z$ productions with $Z\to bZ\mid b$, and a very similar trick will take care of the other problem.

Comment: Thank you, Brian! I understand now. If you are avaiable, could you help me with this other language? L = { w ∈ Σ* | w is a regular expression over a binary alphabet }.
Many thanks!